# Removing StackExchange dropdown and mobile version of auth dialog

Tags: feature-request, api-v2

Would it be possible to remove the StackExchange drop down (hot questions, sites, inbox) from the Auth dialog?

Typically when displaying dialog, you don't want the user to start browsing questions etc (which they probably will do if they see they have an unread inbox item so that the red number is displayed).

Also can a mobile version of the dialog be created at some point before public , basically just make it narrower, and reduce the height of the StackExchange logo?

Comment: Note: you must be referring to the explicit authentication flow since those components are not present in the implicit flow.

Comment: Yes sorry, I meant to say this is the explicit flow.

Comment: Why do you need the explicit flow?

Comment: For a server, I figured it would be more secure to get the access token from the server, rather than have the client download the access token directly and then upload it? But having just said that made me realise that then the client won't be able to use the access token. Tbh I wasn't sure what the point of the explicit flow was?